# Do d-orbital electrons shield each other or not?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals

1. "The shielding of one 4f electron by another is less than that of one d electron by another, and as the nuclear charge increases along the series, there is fairly regular decrease in the size of the entire 4f n orbitals."
2. "One d electron does not shield another electron from the influence of nuclear charge because d-orbitals differ in direction."

Both of the above statements are from the same chapter and are clearly contradicting.One says that d orbitals do shield each other (and that too better than f orbitals), whereas the other says they don't. Where am I going wrong ?

{Reference- ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lech108.pdf page 220, 11th line from top}

Comment: Please quote sources for this to be more useful. You might want to check Slater's rules: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/Chem_1201/Unit_2._Periodic_Properties_of_the_Elements/2.06%3A_Slater%27s_Rules

Comment: A reference would be very useful because as presented "another" in the first quote is ambiguous. Another 4f electron, or another electron in general?

Comment: reference- https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lech108.pdf
page 220, 11th line from top